# Adding one more column to a table

Tags: tables

I need to add one more column to the table and add `$L$` parameter next to `$n$`. How can I add it?

> mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
    \begin{spacing}{1}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}  % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
                \hline
                &   &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{ML }}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{ML  }}  \\
                \cline{3-7}
                $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$& & Train    &  Test      & Train  & Test \\
                \hline
                0.01        & 0.006     & 30  &  & 0.9133    &    \textbf{0.9401}    &       &   \\
                \hline
                0.01        & 0.002     & 50   & &           & &0.8973       &  \textbf{0.9080} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Values.}
            \label{mejorrmsepredictorbase}
        \end{center}
    \end{spacing}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> I am getting something like this, which is awful:

[image]

> I would like to leave it like `$\lambda$` and `\gamma`, meaning, alone.

Comment: Ehm, you just write it into the table ... `&` starts a new column, so you add another `&` at the appropriate place in each row, and new content before it. You've already specified 8 columns for the `tabular`, so you don't have to modify that

Comment: I will try that. Yes, I added the 8. But then I also added & on one row only and it did the opposite

Comment: *Each* row, including the first row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you just need to add an additional `&` and new content in the appropriate position on each row, including the first row. And you need to change the column numbers for the `\crule`. I'm guessing you want `\crule{5-8}`?

I would consider setting the table without vertical rules, it looks better I think. And it's usually recommended using `\centering` instead of the `center` environment, see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides \toprule, \bottomrule,\midrule, \cmidrule
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
    \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}  % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
                \hline
                &  &  &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{ML }}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{ML  }}  \\
                \cline{5-8}
                $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$& $L$ &  Train    &  Test      & Train  & Test \\
                \hline
                0.01        & 0.006  & 30 & 1       & 0.9133    &    \textbf{0.9401}    &       &   \\
                \hline
                0.01        & 0.002  & 50 & 2      &           & &0.8973       &  \textbf{0.9080} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Values.}
            \label{mejorrmsepredictorbase}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
    \centering
            \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
                \toprule
                &  &  &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML}}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML}}  \\
                \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
                $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$& $L$ &  Train    &  Test      & Train  & Test \\
                \midrule
                0.01        & 0.006  & 30 & 1       & 0.9133    &    \textbf{0.9401}    &       &   \\
                0.01        & 0.002  & 50 & 2      &           & &0.8973       &  \textbf{0.9080} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Values.}
            \label{mejorrmsepredictorbase}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW!!!!!! You have a great taste! I really appreciate it! It looks soo good!!!