# Centering label in a table

Tags: tables

> Credits to: Torbjørn T.

I have removed the `$L$` that was posted here: [Torbjørn T example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501185/185467). Now I need to center the second **ML**.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides \toprule, \bottomrule,\midrule, \cmidrule
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \small
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
            \toprule
            &  &  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }} & 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ML }}  \\
            \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
            $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$ &  train    &  test      & train  & test \\
            \midrule
            0.01        & 0.006  & 30        & 0.7130    &    \textbf{0.9243}    &       &   \\
            0.01        & 0.002  & 50       &           & &0.7285       &  \textbf{0.8814} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Values.}
        \label{mejorrmsepredictorbase}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you did not really understand how to use `tabular` and what `\multicolumn` does. I recommend having a look at an introduction, like [this one](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables), and _then the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual_.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides \toprule, \bottomrule,\midrule, \cmidrule
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \small
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
            \toprule
            &  &  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }} &
             \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }}  \\
            \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
            $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$ &  train    &  test      & train  & test \\
            \midrule
            0.01        & 0.006  & 30        & 0.7130    &    \textbf{0.9243}    &       &   \\
            0.01        & 0.002  & 50       &           & &0.7285       &  \textbf{0.8814} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Values.}
        \label{mejorrmsepredictorbase}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

The difference is in this line:

```
&  &  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }} &
             \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }}  \\
```

You had:

```
&  &  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }} & &
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ML }}  \\
```

So you simply have to join two columns (`&
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ML }}`) into one centered (`\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML }}`)

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Good! What’s the difference?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a not so good workaround but it seems to be working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides \toprule, \bottomrule,\midrule, \cmidrule
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \small
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
            \toprule
            &  &  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML 100K}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML 1M}}
              \\
            \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
            $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$ &  train    &  test      & train  & test \\
            \midrule
            0.01        & 0.006  & 30        & 0.7130    &    \textbf{0.9243}    &       &   \\
            0.01        & 0.002  & 50       &           & &0.7285       &  \textbf{0.8814} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Values.}
        \label{mejorrmsepredictorbase}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]